# How to add Firebase Performance Monitoring SDK in Xamarin Forms

Tags: firebase-performance

I am trying to track the app load time. I was suggested to use Firebase analytics, so that I need to add Firebase Performance Monitoring SDK to my app. But I am not able to find any samples to use the same in Xamarin Forms. Please assist me to resolve this.